# Rails: method_missing leads to StackOverflowError

Tags: ruby, stack-overflow, ruby-on-rails-5, method-missing

When triggering a call to method_missing on a Rails server running in development mode, it dies with a `StackOverflowError`. This is a Rails5 on JRuby environment. We are not using multi-threading here.

The behavior can be summarized as follows:

1. The class in which the StackOverflow occurs was written by ourselves. Implementing `def method_missing` and raising from there results in correct behavior (e.g. `fail 'oh noes.'` will print the expected error).
2. Calling super(*args) in the `method_missing` implemented will result in a `StackOverflowError` again.
3. Calling `debugger` right above `super` works and typing `next` reveals that the following calls are:

   - `gems/actionpack-5.0.1.rc2/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22`

     - `request.env['action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions'] ||= show_detailed_exceptions?`
   - `gems/actionpack-5.0.1.rc2/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:23`

     - `rescue_with_handler(exception) || raise`
   - [StackOverflow]
4. In the debug shell (as in point 3), any attempt to get a trace via `backtrace` or `info stack` will result in a StackOverflow.
5. None of this happens when the server is started in test or production environment.

We saw that some code was removed in Rails in [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/6b543166f7b0fd5712ffe831dad31d34f6de5dcd). Indeed, putting the deleted code back in (for testing purposes only) resolves the problem.

Do you think this is a rails bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly solved in https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27481.
Seems like a jruby bug.

Comment: This is a bug in JRuby 9.1.5.0 that appears to be fixed in JRuby 9.1.6.0